# Golang Testify Mock does not return specified values

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, testify

I've mocked a repository interface and I want to return a specific value when a method is called. However, it always returns what's in the dummy implementation.

```
type MockUserRepo struct {
  mock.Mock
}

// dummy method to fulfil the interface
func (m *MockUserRepo) FindByUsername(username string) (*User, error) {
    return nil, nil 
}
```

Now, I setup the mock as such

```
m := NewMockUserRepo()
m.On("FindByUsername", mock.Anything).Return(&User{
    Username: "test"
}, nil)

// inject mock
svc := NewService(m)
user, err := svc.FindByUsername("anything") // always nil,nil
```

The return value (`user, err`) is always `nil` (or whatever is returned in `MockUserRepo.FindByUsername`

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *"Is there something I'm doing wrong?"* -- Yes. Compare your implementation of `*MockUserRepo.FindByUsername` to that of the package's example usage doc:  [`*MyTestObject.SavePersonDetails`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#hdr-Example_Usage) (basically you're missing the `Called()` and the `args.Get(0).(*User)`)

Comment: But `args.Get(0)` is `string`. Not `*User`. Basically, I don't care about the args.

Comment: *"But `args.Get(0)` is `string`"*. [It is not](https://go.dev/play/p/5BMEO5BO7Ml). You haven't even tried to type in the two suggested lines and execute to code to see it pass. Why? The word "args" doesn't necessarily have to mean input arguments, there's also such a thing as "return argument".

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#Arguments => *"Arguments holds an array of method arguments or **return values**."*

Answer (score 0):

source : https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock#hdr-Example_Usage

> For objects of your own type, use the generic Arguments.Get(index) method and make a type assertion: `return args.Get(0).(*MyObject), args.Get(1).(*AnotherObjectOfMine)`

So in your `FindByUsername` method change to this:

```golang
func (m *MockUserRepo) FindByUsername(username string) (*User, error) {
    args := m.Called(username)
    return args.Get(0).(*User), args.Error(1)
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/oLPy0LT0DHy)